# Varnish appears to be working but max-age=0

Tags: ubuntu, caching, http-headers, apache2, varnish

isvarnishworking.com is letting me know that

> Varnish appears to be responding at that url, but the Cache-Control
>   header's "max-age" value is less than 1, which means that Varnish will
>   never serve content from cache at this url.
>
> The max-age value appears to be: 0

And this header info

```
The url we checked: myDomainHere.com
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vgk7db66kh7nce8lpe5789u105; path=/
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary:   Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Type:   text/html
Content-Length: 14192
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Date:   Sat, 18 Jul 2015 09:31:55 GMT
X-Varnish:  324589322
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have this in .htaccess

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

So my question, Do I really have to change that max-age=0 in order to varnish perform better? If so, where would I Do this? I am using apache2 on a ubuntu digitalocean's droplet

-edit-

This is my `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
#
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
#
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
#
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
# sub vcl_recv {
#     if (req.restarts == 0) {
#       if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
#           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
#               req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
#       } else {
#           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
#       }
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" &&
#       req.request != "HEAD" &&
#       req.request != "PUT" &&
#       req.request != "POST" &&
#       req.request != "TRACE" &&
#       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
#       req.request != "DELETE") {
#         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
#         return (pipe);
#     }
#     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
#         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
#         /* Not cacheable by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (lookup);
# }
#
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
#
```

Comment: may it be cause i'm using session on the code? but I created an .html, tested it and result was the same..

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure, Varnish 3.x and 4.x are both available. Run `varnishd -V`, they are quite different so it's better to be sure.

Comment: varnishd (varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8), and I updated question with .vcl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I really have to change that max-age=0 in order to varnish perform
> better?

**Yes.** You *need* to do it if you want it to perform at all.

> If so, where would I Do this?

It seems you got everything right for caching static content, but you also seem to want to cache PHP script execution responses:

**You are just missing [session_cache_limiter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) and [session_cache_expire](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php), which should be the first lines executed on the requested PHP script, even before `session_start()`**.

If, for example, the content returned is private and you want to refresh it every minute, try something like:

```
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(1);
```

After that you should see a proper `Cache-Control:  max-age=60, private` value on Varnish responses for requests for PHP generated content including those lines at the beginning of the script.

**[update]** Seeing your problem isn't solved yet, maybe you should try to use Apache mod_expires instead of manually setting the Cache-Control header: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html

That should answer your questions, but allow me to give you a few extra notes that may be useful to you and help you get a better understanding on how Varnish and the `Cache-Control` header relate to each other:

- With the default configuration `max-age=0` on the response indicates both to Varnish and to the
  browser that the response is not cacheable. Unless configured otherwise or explicitly allowed on the client's request, Varnish [will not serve stale content](https://www.varnish-software.com/book/3/HTTP.html#expires):

> A stale cache item will not be returned by any cache (proxy cache or
> client cache).

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3:

> If a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-age
> directive (Section 5.2.2.8), a recipient MUST ignore the Expires
> field.  Likewise, if a response includes the s-maxage directive
> (Section 5.2.2.9), a shared cache recipient MUST ignore the Expires
> field.  In both these cases, the value in Expires is only intended
> for recipients that have not yet implemented the Cache-Control field.

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3:

> If a cache returns a stale response, either because of a max-stale
> directive on a request, or because the cache is configured to override
> the expiration time of a response, the cache MUST attach a Warning
> header to the stale response, using Warning 110 (Response is stale).
>
> A cache MAY be configured to return stale responses without
> validation, but only if this does not conflict with any "MUST"-level
> requirements concerning cache validation (e.g., a "must-revalidate"
> cache-control directive).
>
> If both the new request and the cached entry include "max-age"
> directives, then the lesser of the two values is used for determining
> the freshness of the cached entry for that request.

- The main purpose of Varnish is to store in-memory cacheable responses
  (while they are fresh) so they can be sent to the same OR different
  clients without regenerating them, also facilitating load balancing
  if required.
- Varnish will not serve stale content when requested fresh content
  (most common scenario) and even if it did, [the browser would not be
  saving it](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) and would generate a new request for a fresh page every
  time the user asked for that content, unnecessarily hitting the cache
  (with all the network activity involved) instead of rendering a
  locally stored copy, which would be quite inefficient and noticeably
  slower!

> max-age Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response
> whose age is no greater than the specified time in seconds. Unless
> max- stale directive is also included, the client is not willing to
> accept a stale response.

- If something isn't clear yet, you can check out [varnish
  documentation on Cache-Control](https://www.varnish-software.com/book/3/HTTP.html#cache-control) for more detailed info.

Now, if you still see the browser sends a new request every time the content is loaded (check the network tab of your browser's developer tools or [varnish logs](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/05/configure-varnish-logs-varnishnsca-logrotate-and-awstats-1014/)), recheck everything. As a last resort you can also [try to set the proper html meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers), although [html5 deprecates them](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2011Oct/0017.html) and they shouldn't be necessary for any modern browser and it is not best practice so I would advise against it.

Also here is [some good reading](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/intelligent-php-cache-control/) on doing proper cache control on content generated by PHP scripts that might interest you.

Comment: Thank your for such an elaborated answer! I tried `session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(1);` and it didn't change any of the isvarnishworking.com results... also the html `<meta>` tags... any other thing you think I could try? thanks again!

Comment: are you calling `session_start();` afterwards? If not, you cannot set the limiter to private. Also you may try to manually set the Cache-Control header instead, by replacing both calls with `header("Cache-Control: max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate");`

Comment: More importantly, recheck your Apache configuration files. The origin of the error is most likely there (maybe you are overriding your configuration somewhere?). A good place to start would be using mod_expires instead of manually setting Cache-Control headers: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: I awared you the bounty even that my problem is not resolved, but it's indeed a great answer!

Comment: I work with varnish regularly and I have had to solve a few problems already, although it is usually quite simple to set up and it does a pretty good job once you get it to work. I will let you know if I come up with any other possible cause for this outcome. Now I've got so invested I really need to know what's happening! Please tell me if you find out :-)

Comment: I apreciate your time a lot... this is my whole htacess (just with not rewrite rules) http://pastebin.com/LCenyNFh In case anything pops out your mind, cheers!

Comment: I've noticed a couple of things: isvarnishworking.com you doesn't seem to be actually getting a `max-age=0`. The dump you posted has a `max-age=60`. Then, why the error? Well, you also have an `Expires` header, which should be overriden by `max-age` so its value is not a big deal but anyway it reads `Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`. This is probably due to an unset system clock in your Apache/Varnish server machine, and it is probably causing an incorrect `Age:0 `header which is probably interpreted by isvarnishworking.com as something being wrong with the response caching.

Comment: isvarnishworking.com is telling you something like: "come on, you are telling me you have been caching this content for a whole of 0 seconds every time I ask for it? That's a little suspicious!". Although for private content if a session cookie is not provided or is not validated, starting a new session implies generating and sending Age:0 content. A lot of maybes, but that's all I've got. I suggest you sync the problematic system clock using ntp: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html and then recheck to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Something else: your .htaccess is wrong. Remove the `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"` directive from .htaccess. You don't need it if you are already using `ExpiresByType`/`ExpiresDefault` (Check the examples on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html to see how to use the directives. The apache mime types configuration file, located in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf in ubuntu can also be useful for determine which mime types are associated with the extension you want to set caching times for)

Comment: Also, I don't know which is the highest load peak you are expecting to serve, but even the cheapest server (let's say, a 6USD/month EC2 instance), with pretty much a standard configuration, can serve up to 40-50 simultaneous requests for a typical PHP page (or even a kinda heavy one with DB access and all such as a wordpress front page) without significant impact in the page load times (this is from my personal blog: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GaelAbadin/posts/2km96GkBQcS?pid=6096084785794746850&oid=100532267028694326619). Consider that, just in case it is not worth your time and trouble.

Comment: I tried `ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com` and restarting apache2 and varnish, and same result... Yes, I know that there is not a real need, but  just like you I'm curious, I hope to get bigger traffic and I might need it then.. ;) Really, thanks for every tip!

Answer (score 1):

Your Varnish VCL is not sufficient. Search and use corresponding VCL 3 or VCL 4 template, according to your Varnish version.

Check your Varnish version: varnishd -V

If you use version 2, upgrade to version 3 or 4.

VCL for Varnish 3:
https://github.com/dreamhost/varnish-vcl-collection

VCL for Varnish 4:
https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl